# Unexpected behavior in Magento collection filters used in loops

Tags: magento

I'm seeing an unexpected behavior in collections that maybe someone can enlighten me on (or maybe it's a bit of PHP I don't grok) (sorry for the length of this post, but I had to include sample code and results).

My goal was to write a report where I get an order and it's order items, then go to the invoice and shipment data for the order and get the matching order item data from their items.  I know that there is only one invoice and shipment for all orders, so even though Magento uses a 1-M relationship between orders and invoices/shipments, I can take advantage of it as if it were 1-1

I know that the items are all related using the order_item_id fields, so I tried to write a function that used the the following call -

```
$invoiceItem = $order
  ->getInvoiceCollection()
  ->getFirstItem()
  ->getItemsCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $orderItem->getItemId())
  ->getFirstItem();
```

But that didn't results I expected, what I saw was the same invoice item returned regardless of the order item id used in the filter.

So, to try to understand the problem, I wrote the following small program to see how the queries where created.

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/Mage.php';    
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
       ->addAttributeToFilter('state', 'processing') 
       ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
       ->addAttributeToSort('status', 'asc')
       ->load();

foreach ($orders as $order) {

    echo "\ngetting data for order id ". $order->getId();

    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    $invoice = $order->getInvoiceCollection()->getFirstItem();

    foreach ($items as $orderItem) {

        echo "\n\ngetting data for order item id ". $orderItem->getItemId();    
        $invoiceItems = $order
                   ->getInvoiceCollection()
                   ->getFirstItem()
                   ->getItemsCollection()
                   ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $orderItem->getItemId());    
        echo "\n".$invoiceItems->getSelect();    
    }
    die;  //just quit after one iteration
}
```

The output from this program was the following -

```
getting data for order id 7692

getting data for order item id 20870
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_invoice_item` AS `main_table` WHERE (parent_id = '7623') AND (order_item_id = '20870')

getting data for order item id 20871
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_invoice_item` AS `main_table` WHERE (parent_id = '7623') AND (order_item_id = '20870') AND (order_item_id = '20871')

getting data for order item id 20872
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_invoice_item` AS `main_table` WHERE (parent_id = '7623') AND (order_item_id = '20870') AND (order_item_id = '20871') AND (order_item_id = '20872')
```

As you can see, every time though the loop another "AND (order_item_id =" was added for each item Id that I was filtering on.  I thought that every time though the loop, I'd be getting a fresh version of the collection from using $order->getInvoiceCollection().

So, can anyone tell me what's going wrong in my sample code and educate me on the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Manipulating `$order` alters its contents. I'm guessing if you recast `$order` each iteration (not necessarily efficient) it would work. Inside the foreach|$orderItem, try `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId())`. If that works you should get some insight from there.

Answer (score 0):

*Regarding your business question: need more info. Is the goal to generate a collection with order item objects which are EACH aware of invoice and shipment details? It seems like there are rendering concerns getting pushed into modeling concerns.*

Regarding the select statement question: [Varien collections](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php) have an optimization which prevents them from accessing the storage backend  more than once. This standard behavior is achieved in [DB collection](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php) instances by setting the `_isCollectionLoaded` property to `true`.

In your case, the invoice collection instance is created via the order instance [*stored in a protected property*](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1869), and [immediately `load()`ed](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1874) via `IteratorAggregate` (invoked via `foreach`). Because you are using the same order object instance in each iteration, you are dealing with this loaded invoice collection instance and are effectively calling `addFieldToFilter(/* next order id */)` with each iteration, resulting in the ever-expanding `WHERE` clause. This specific  optimization can easily be worked around by calling `$order->reset()`. This brings us back to the salient issue though, which is the need to better understand the goal and (likely) use a custom collection or to manipulate a collection to join in the specific data that you need.

Comment: Thanks Ben, So, everytime you call load() or getFirstItem() Magento is not reloading the data from the database?

Comment: Thanks Ben - So, everytime you call load() or getFirstItem() Magento is not refetching from the database.  I thought those calls would  reload the data, and therefore rebuild the collections. Since the business use here was just a quick one-off report where I needed to show order_items and their matching invoice_items,I was trying to use existing models to provide the data.  I'll just iterate through the existing invoice & shipment items collections to find the ones that relate to the order items.